# Is divide by zero an error or an exception?

Tags: exception, programming-languages, error-handling

Basically I want to know how do you differentiate an error from an exception. In some programming languages accessing a  non existent file throws an error and in others its an exception. How do you know if some thing is an error or an exception?

Comment: In many languages, exceptions don't exist or are the only (language-integrated, widely used - i.e. relevant in practice) error handling mechanism. Other languages have several error handling mechanism. And in both kinds, there might be disagreement what should go in which category. I don't think there's a language agnostic answer.

Answer (score 2):

Like anything else - you either test it or read the documentation. It can be an "Error" or an "Exception" based on the language.

Eg.

**C:**

Crashes and gives a divide by zero error.

**Ruby:**

```
>> 6 / 0
ZeroDivisionError: divided by 0
from (irb):1:in `/'
from (irb):1
```

(ZeroDivisionError is actually an exception.)

**Java:**

Code:

```
int x = 6 / 0;
```

Output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
```

Comment: ZeroDivisionError is an exception

Comment: Ah you're right. I updated it, using the obvious C as one that errors.

Comment: +1 for "the only way to know is to test it or read the documentation".

Answer (score 1):

**It depends on the language** :

- some languages don't have exceptions
- some languages don't use exceptions for everything.

For example, in PHP :

- There are exceptions
- But divide by 0 doesn't cause an exception to be thrown : is only raises a warning -- that doesn't stop the execution of the script.

The following portion of code :

```
echo 10 / 0;
echo "hello, world!";
```

Would give this result :

```
Warning: Division by zero in /.../temp.php on line 5
hello, world!
```

Answer (score 1):

The terms *error* and *exception* are commonly used as jargon terms, with meanings that vary depending upon the programming ecosystem in which they are used.

### Conditions

This response follows the lead of [Common Lisp](http://www.cs.williams.edu/~freund/cs334/auxread/cltl/clm/node314.html), and adopts the term *condition* as a nonjudgmental way of referring to an "interesting situation" in a program.

What makes a program condition "interesting"?  Let's consider the division-by-zero case for real numbers.  In the overwhelming majority of cases in which one real is divided by another, the result is another plain ordinary well-behaved real number.  These are the "routine" or "uninteresting" cases.  However, in the case that the divisor is zero then, mathematically speaking, the result is undefined.  The program is now in an "interesting" or "exceptional" condition.

It becomes even more complicated once we take the mathematical ideal of a real number and model it, say, as an [IEEE-format floating point number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating-point_standard).  If we divide 1.0 / 0.0, the IEEE standard (mostly) says that the result is in fact another floating point number, the quiet NaN *Infinity*.  Since the result no longer behaves in the same way as a plain old real number, the program condition is once again "interesting" or "exceptional".

### Classifying Conditions

The question is: what should we do when we run into an interesting condition?  The answer is dependent upon the context.  When classifying program conditions, the following questions are useful:

1. How likely is it that the condition will occur: certain, probable, unlikely, impossible?
2. How is the condition detected: program malfunction, distinguished value, signal/handler (aka [exception handling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_handling)), program termination?
3. How should the condition be handled: ignore it, perform some special action, terminate the program?

The answers to these questions yield 4 x 4 x 3 = 48 distinct cases -- and surely more could be distinguished by further criteria.  This brings us to the heart of the matter.  We have more than two cases but only two labels, *error* and *exception*, to apply to them.  Needless to say, there are many possible ways to divide the 48+ cases into two groups.

For example, one could say that anything involving program malfunction is an *error*, anything else is an *exception*.  Or that anything involving a language's built-in [exception handling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_handling) facilities is an *exception*, anything else is an *error*.  The possibilities are legion.

### Examples

#### End-Of-File

When reading and processing a stream of characters, hitting the end-of-file is certain.  In C, this event is detected by means of a distinguished return value from an I/O function, a so-called *error* return value.  Thus, one speaks of an EOF *error*.

#### Division-By-Zero

When dividing two user-entered numbers in a simple calculator program, we want to give a meaningful result even if the user enters a divisor of zero.  In some C environments, division-by-zero results in a *signal* ([SIGFPE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGFPE)) that must be fielded by a signal handler.  Signals are sometimes called *exceptions* in the C community and, confusingly, sometimes called program *error* signals.  In other C environments, IEEE floating-point rules apply and the division-by-zero would result in a NaN value.  The C environment would be blissfully unaware of that value, considering it to be neither an *exception* nor an *error*.

#### Runtime Load Failure

Programs frequently load their program code dynamically at run-time (e.g. classes, DLLs).  This might fail due to a missing file.  C offers no standard way to detect or recover from this case.  The program would be terminated involuntarily, and one often speaks of this situation as a fatal *exception*.  In Java, this would be termed a linkage *error*.

#### Java's *Throwable* Hierarchy

Java's exception-handling system divides the so-called [Throwable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html) class hierarchy into two main groups.  Subclasses of `Error` are meant to represent conditions from which recovery is impossible.  Subclasses of `Exception` are meant for recoverable conditions are are further subdivided into checked exceptions (for probable conditions) and unchecked exceptions (for unlikely conditions).  Unfortunately, the boundaries between these categories are poorly defined and you will often find instances of throwables whose semantics suggest that they belong in a different category.

### Be Wary Of Jargon

These examples show that the meanings of *error* and *exception* are murky at best.  One must treat *error* and *exception* as jargon, whose meaning is determined by the context of discussion.

Of greater value are distinguishing characteristics of program conditions.  What is the likelihood of the condition occurring?  How is the condition detected?  What action should be taken when the condition is detected?  In any discussion that demands clarity, one is better suited to answer these questions directly rather than relying upon jargon terminology.

Comment: Looking at Java, I can "recover" from an exception. I, as a program, can still survive if the file I want to read doesn't exist and tell this nicely and ask for a actual file. But in some other language, say plain vanilla C, I die if I try to read a non existent file. Of course I can check if the file exists but when I try to access a non existent file w/out checking its existence will be frowned upon. I have an opinion that errors are not exceptions and both are different. After reading your warning, I think I may have to change my opinion.

Comment: I never had a chance to work in Java or .NET, mingled with C and C++ but am more of a web developer :)

Answer (score 0):

Exceptions should indicate exceptional activity, so if you reach a point in your code for which you've done your best to avoid divide by zero, then throwing an exception (if you are able to in your language) is the right way.

If it's routine logic to check for divide by zero (like for a calculator app) then you should check for that in your code before it has the chance to raise an exception.  In that case, it's an error (in user input) and should be handled as such.

(Stole this idea either from The Pragmatic Programmer or Code Complete; can't remember which.)