# Methods of reusing error messages

Tags: php, zend-framework, error-handling, php-5.3

We are using PHP 5.3 and Zend Framework for a large project, and I've run into a problem of convenience.  We reuse the same error messages over and over again in different parts of the application, like "You don't have permission to complete this action."  Does anyone have any unique ways of reusing error messages so we don't have to rewrite them over and over again?

My first thought was to do something simple like this:

```
class ErrorMessage
{
    const ERROR_NO_PERMS = 'noPerms';
    const ERROR_INT = 'int';

    protected static $_messages = array(
        self::ERROR_NO_PERMS => 'You do not have permission to complete this action',
        self::ERROR_INT      => "'%s' must be an integer",
    );

    public static get($errorCode)
    {
        if (!array_key_exists($errorCode, self::$_messages)) {
            // error
        }

        // check for translation

        return self::$_messages[$errorCode];
    }
}
```

What would you do?  (Keep in mind that we would like this to be integrated with ZF, so we are open to any ideas that extend into native ZF classes.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could also created "named exceptions".

```
class PermissionException extends Exception
{
  public function __toString()
  {
    return 'You do not have permission!';
  }
}
```

If ZF has own exceptions, you can extend those. Or you can extend one of the already available [PHP exceptions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/spl.exceptions.php).

Comment: So essentially, you could throw a custom exception, allow ZF's ErrorController to intercept it, convert it to a string, and return the string to the user.  Interesting.  I will give this some thought.  Thanks for your contribution.

Comment: You can cast it explicitly into a string, but that's not needed. In a string context, PHP automatically runs the `__toString()` method in order to "stringify" the exception object. So an `echo $e;` where `$e` is the caught exception is enough.

Comment: A PermissionException should not exist though because a user making a request which s/he isnt permitted is to be expected and not exceptional at all. The system should simply respond with a 401 or 403 header and an appropriate message.

Comment: @Gordon I beg to differ. If a method expects a user to be logged in and have the proper permissions, NOT having the permissions is an exception. - Just another example: Division by zero. Is a DivisionByZeroException exceptional? After all it is expected if the the divisor can be freely given, as in `7 / $a`.

Comment: A Division by Zero isnt exceptional and only triggers a Warning in PHP. If that is an issue to the Application, there should be proper boundary checking before doing the division. Throwing an Exception for NotPermitted is abusing Exceptions for control flow because you already know you will catch and redirect.

Comment: @Gordon: You could argue the same about the user making a request to a non existent page, which currently causes an exception in ZF, which is in turned handled gracefully by the error controller (which sets the appropriate 404 header). With your suggestion how do you avoid repeating your error + message code in multiple places, how do you handle it in situations that can't easily set headers (e.g. service classes), how would you log these errors? I agree with your objections but I still think this is the "least worst" solution.

Comment: Right: `if ($divisor == 0)`, and what then? Return `NULL`, return `FALSE`? I'd throw an exception.

Comment: You should do this anyway. That's how a `catch` works: to only catch a certain type of exception eg. Access Denied. It would be 'silly' to put all your (types of) exceptions in one type `Zend_Exception` (or whatever they're called in ZF).

Comment: @Shi 1/0 returns false in PHP. I'd prefer NaN.

Comment: @Tim I'm not saying it's a bad solution. Im just saying that the example is a bit suboptimal. Tbh, I do think ZF isnt a good example for exception use. They are just inflational with them. That Error Controller is often enough abused as a giant catch-all when the exceptions should be handled close to where they happen and not bubble all the way up. As for not repeating error messages: shouldnt be too much of an issue if you raise errors where they happen instead of querying if they happenend and then raising them.

Comment: @Gordon Yes, I know. But if using `FALSE` in a numerical context, it will be casted into `0`. But if a mathematical expression should be evaluated and a float is expected as return value, a `FALSE` does not make sense. That's why an exception should be thrown. But I guess you have your opinions, I have mine. And if we all had the same, life would be boring. So cheers and enjoy. :)

Comment: @Shi cheers, and we are not the only ones to disagree on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5436476/is-divide-by-zero-an-error-or-an-exception ;)